# Connecting Android Application to Python Server

Tags: python, android, networking

I'm writing a program to send a String object (and eventually image, but starting small) from an Android Application to a python server.

My python server is pretty small right now it just listens and then prints what it receives.

```
import socket
import sys
print("---------------------------------------------")
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_addy = ("localhost", 5589)
print("starting up on %s with port %s" % server_addy)
socket.bind(server_addy)
socket.listen(1)
while True:
    print("Waiting on connection...")
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    connection, client_addy = socket.accept()
    print("Connection Accepted")
try:
    print("Connection received from...", client_addy)
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        print("Received \" %s \" from connection" % data)
        connection.close()
        break
finally:
    print("Closing Connection to ", client_addy)
    connection.close()
```

I've tested this with another python client that is able to connect to and send/receive data from this server.
So on my Android App side I have

```
public class score_verify extends AppCompatActivity {

private String input_score;
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
private Socket socket;
private String url = "localhost";
private String metadata;
private int port = 5589;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_verify);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    final EditText score = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    final CheckBox box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.verify);
    metadata = getIntent().getStringExtra("metadata");
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            input_score = score.getText().toString();
            if(!pattern.matcher(input_score).matches()) {
                Toast.makeText(score_verify.this, "Please Enter A Valid Score", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(!box.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(score_verify.this, "Please Verify that the Information is Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                try {
                    metadata += ("," + input_score);
                    metadataTask task = new metadataTask();
                    task.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

With the actual connection code being

```
private class metadataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    PrintWriter printWriter;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(url, 5589);
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.write("Connecting!...");
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

For the first section where I have URL I've tried it with "127.0.0.1", "localhost", and "10.0.2.2" and I get either a connection timeout or a (with localhost) a connection refused error.

I have

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

both in my manifest as well
Any help at all would be appreciated, I'm at about the end of my ability to diagnose this problem

Ping Results:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.89 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.232: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.89: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.89: bytes=32 time=130ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.89: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.89:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 37ms, Maximum = 130ms, Average = 72ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Your python code seems to be accepting connection continuously forever in while loop, which prevent it from enter the try block. Also changed the address parameter in `server_addy` to    `server_addy = ('', "port")`
Providing you with the code below

```
import socket
import sys
print("---------------------------------------------")
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_addy = ('', 5600)
print("starting up on %s with port %s" % server_addy)
socket.bind(server_addy)
socket.listen(1)
while True:
    print("Waiting on connection...")
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    connection, client_addy = socket.accept()
    print("Connection Accepted")
    try:
       print("Connection received from...", client_addy)
       while True:
                 data = connection.recv(1024)
                 print("Received \" %s \" from connection" % data)
                 connection.close()
                 break
    finally:
           print("Closing Connection to ", client_addy)
           connection.close()
```

This will serve single client connection at a time and upon closing of connection   it will accept next connection. 
And in the android part use either of the two address to connect:

- your private IP address (192.168.0.0)
- Or, 10.0.2.2

Comment: Hi and thanks so much for the help! I changed the python server to your suggestion and added tried the Android program with both the 192 and the 10 locations. Doing the 192.168.0.0 I got a connection refused error and doing the 10.0.2.2 I got a connection timeout.

Comment: No, I’m using a physical phone

Comment: can you try to ping the private ip 192.168.  through your PC

Comment: The ip address of the phone?

Comment: Editing original post with ping results

Comment: Alright then, it getting challenging more and more. Can you try to use telnet command to make sure whether the port is listening (command:    telnet <your Server private ip> <python port>

Comment: I was able to successfully telnet into the python port

Comment: In your android code, use the private IP (192.168._._) to connect

Comment: Oh man it worked! I connected it to my PC's IP and it worked just fine! Thanks so much for all your help!!!!

Comment: Nither 10.0.2.2 or localhost will work in actual physical device, I would have ask for your test device earlier

Comment: It’s all good, I should’ve specified I was using a physical phone from the getgo. Thanks for sticking with me!